# Android connection to database doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I try to use database (sql server management studio). I have simple login from - username and password. I want when the user click the button login to check if this username and password exist in database. If exist to return new activity, if not exist to popup message with message "Username not found". I have popup message, but connection to the database is not working

This is my main activity

```
package com.example.cinemaweb;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=AdminToolWeb";
                String user = "mssqllogin";
                String pass = "mssqllogin$";

                EditText usernameUser = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText);
                EditText passwordUser = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText2);
                try {
                    Class.forName("om.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

                    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("select * from Accounts where Username_DB = '" + usernameUser + "' and Password_DB = '" + passwordUser + "'");
                    if (resultat.next()) {

                        setContentView(R.layout.login_successfully);
                    } else {
                        openDialog();
                    }
                    resultat.close();
                    statement.close();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="145dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="363dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="270dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Потребителско име"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="202dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Парола"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:shadowRadius="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Вход" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is from Logcat

```
2021-05-03 15:41:57.790 382-416/com.example.cinemaweb D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ffff2000 size 0x2000
2021-05-03 15:41:57.803 382-416/com.example.cinemaweb D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd581a360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd580f1e0)
2021-05-03 15:42:00.978 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1664 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
2021-05-03 15:42:06.617 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: om.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
2021-05-03 15:42:06.617 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.617 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.617 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.618 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at com.example.cinemaweb.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.618 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.618 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.619 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.620 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.620 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.620 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.620 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.620 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.620 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.620 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.621 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.621 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "om.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.cinemaweb-J6hpkxclJDJrZ3kfh7wOzw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.cinemaweb-J6hpkxclJDJrZ3kfh7wOzw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
2021-05-03 15:42:06.621 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.621 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.621 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
2021-05-03 15:42:06.621 382-382/com.example.cinemaweb W/System.err:     ... 15 more
```

If u have any idea what is the problem, tell me please

Comment: If you run that query directly in the database, is it working?

Comment: What does it mean by "doesn't work"? What are the errors printed at the logcat?

Comment: query is working, the problem is in connection to the database. This connection is from java spring project. I just copied from this project

Comment: FYI, if u wanted to implement database in your Android app, I strongly suggest [Android Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). It's really easy to learn and use and I'm personally using it.

Comment: it is not a good practice to create a connection from mobile to sql server. this is why backend languages exist. you should write a web service with python or php ... to connect to database change the status and send the response to you. android apps use sqlite internally for their data and change database server via web service request.

Comment: This is for project from the university. I want to Directlly connect to the database and show some data.

Comment: should the connection be from android app?

Comment: should you use database on the server for this assignment?

Comment: Have you set up connection settings for your database in your application?

Comment: @AliMomeni connection is from java spring project, I don't know how to change it to work for android app. I use sql server management studio, because my main java spring project use this database. I want android app to show the data from database

Comment: @LajosArpad in the app, no. I just coppy driver, connection string, username, password for other java spring project

Comment: right thing to do if you have a java spring app is to send a restful request from android to java spring app and from spring app you call the database and what ever the result is send it back to android app.

Comment: that is, there is no way to connect the database directly to the Android project?